# What proportion of $n m \times n m$ positive-definite fixed-trace symmetric (Hermitian) matrices remain positive-definite under a certain operation?

Tags: matrices, measure-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, singular-values

Given the class of $n m \times n m$ positive-definite (symmetric or Hermitian) fixed-trace (say, 1), $n,m\geq 2$, what "proportion" of the class remains positive-definite if either the $n^2$ blocks of size $m \times m$  or the $m^2$ blocks of size $n \times n$ are transposed in place?

Further, how might the answer to the question depend upon $k$, where
the rank of the matrices under consideration is fixed at $k \leq n m$?

Answer (score 4):

Let us denote the matrices in question by $\rho_{nm}$ and, first, consider the use of the measure generated by the Hilbert-Schmidt metric
\begin{equation}
\mbox{d} s^2_{HS}=\frac{1}{2} \mbox{Tr}[(\mbox{d} \rho_{nm})^2].
\end{equation}

Then, A. Lovas and A. Andai

[LovasAndaiPaper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01410)  MR3673324

have formally answered the question for the case of symmetric $\rho_{22}$, obtaining the value $\frac{29}{64}$ for the proportion ("separability probability") of this nine-dimensional set of "two-rebit density matrices" that remain positive-definite under the indicated operation of "partial transposition".

In their Conclusions, Lovas and Andai write: ``The structure of the unit ball in operator norm of $2\times 2$ matrices plays a
critical role in separability probability of qubit-qubit and rebit-rebit
quantum systems.
It is quite surprising that the space of $2\times 2$ real or complex matrices
seems simple, but to compute the volume of the set
\begin{equation*}
\Big\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c& e\end{pmatrix} \Big\vert\ a, b, c, e \in \mathbb{K},
 \Big| \Big|{\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c& e\end{pmatrix}} \Big| \Big| <1,\ \
  \Big| \Big|{\begin{pmatrix} a & \varepsilon b\\ \frac{c}{\varepsilon}& e
\end{pmatrix}}  <1  \Big| \Big|\Big\}
\end{equation*}
for a given parameter $\varepsilon\in [0,1]$, which is the value of
the function $\chi_{d}(\varepsilon)$, is a very challenging problem.
The gist of our considerations is that the behavior of the function
$\chi_{d}(\varepsilon)$ determines the separability probabilities with respect
to the Hilbert-Schmidt measure.'' (The operator norm $ \Big| \Big| \hspace{.15in} \Big| \Big|$ is the largest singular value or Schatten-$\infty$ norm.)

The function $\chi_{1}(\varepsilon)$--found employing an auxiliary "defect function"--which is used for the determination of the $\frac{29}{64}$ is given by
\begin{equation} \label{BasicFormula}
\tilde{\chi}_1 (\varepsilon ) = 1-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int\limits_\varepsilon^1 
\left(
s+\frac{1}{s}-
\frac{1}{2}\left(s-\frac{1}{s}\right)^2\log \left(\frac{1+s}{1-s}\right)
\right)\frac{1}{s}
\mbox{d}  s 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 = \frac{4}{\pi^2}\int\limits_0^\varepsilon
\left(
s+\frac{1}{s}-
\frac{1}{2}\left(s-\frac{1}{s}\right)^2\log \left(\frac{1+s}{1-s}\right)
\right)\frac{1}{s}
\mbox{d} s .
\end{equation}
Let us note that
$\tilde{\chi}_1 (\varepsilon )$ has a closed form,
\begin{equation} \label{poly}
\frac{2 \left(\varepsilon ^2 \left(4 \text{Li}_2(\varepsilon )-\text{Li}_2\left(\varepsilon
   ^2\right)\right)+\varepsilon ^4 \left(-\tanh ^{-1}(\varepsilon )\right)+\varepsilon ^3-\varepsilon
   +\tanh ^{-1}(\varepsilon )\right)}{\pi ^2 \varepsilon ^2},    
\end{equation}
where the polylogarithmic function is defined by the infinite sum
\begin{equation*}
    \text{Li}_s (z) =
    \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 
    \frac{z^k}{k^s},
\end{equation*}
for arbitrary complex $s$ and for all complex arguments $z$ with $|z|<1$.

Lovas and Andai left unanswered the (two-qubit) matter of (15-dimensional) Hermitian $\rho_{22}$.

In [MasterLovasAndai](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-018-1854-5) MR3767844

Slater was able to construct--though yet without formalized proof--the much simpler
\begin{equation} \label{BasicFormula2}
\tilde{\chi}_2 (\varepsilon ) = \frac{1}{3} \varepsilon^2 (4-\varepsilon^2)
\end{equation}
leading to the two-qubit separability probability of $\frac{8}{33}$.

Also, in this paper, counterparts were given for quaternionic [$\tilde{\chi}_4 (\varepsilon ) = \frac{1}{35} \varepsilon^4 (84-64\varepsilon^2+15 \varepsilon^4)$ yielding $\frac{26}{323}$],...density matrices.

Then, these three formulas were incorporated into a "Master Lovas-Andai" formula--the index $d$ being a form of "Dyson-index" of random matrix theory-
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\chi}_d (\varepsilon ) = \frac{\varepsilon^d \Gamma(d+1)^3 \, _3\tilde{F}_2\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2},d;\frac{d}{2}+1,\frac{3 d}{2}+1;\varepsilon^2\right)}{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}+1)^2},
\end{equation}
where the regularized hypergeometric function is indicated.

For $\alpha=\frac{d}{2}$, the desired probabilities ($\frac{29}{64}, \frac{8}{33},\ldots$) are yielded by
\begin{equation} \label{Hou1}
P(\alpha) =\Sigma_{i=0}^\infty f(\alpha+i),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation} \label{Hou2}
f(\alpha) = P(\alpha)-P(\alpha +1) = \frac{ q(\alpha) 2^{-4 \alpha -6} \Gamma{(3 \alpha +\frac{5}{2})} \Gamma{(5 \alpha +2})}{6 \Gamma{(\alpha +1)} \Gamma{(2 \alpha +3)} 
\Gamma{(5 \alpha +\frac{13}{2})}},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} \label{Hou3}
q(\alpha) = 185000 \alpha ^5+779750 \alpha ^4+1289125 \alpha ^3+1042015 \alpha ^2+410694 \alpha +63000 = 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\alpha  \bigg(5 \alpha  \Big(25 \alpha  \big(2 \alpha  (740 \alpha
   +3119)+10313\big)+208403\Big)+410694\bigg)+63000.
\end{equation}
(Qing-Hu Hou helped in the derivation of this formula, using "Zeilberger's algorithm" ["creative telescoping"] [ConciseFormula](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/46/44/445302/meta).)

An equivalent formula--now employing $d$ rather than $\alpha=\frac{d}{2}$--was given by C. F. Dunkl in App. D of [MasterLovasAndai](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-018-1854-5)
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}(d)  =3456^{d}\frac{\left(  \frac{1}{2}\right)  _{d/2}%
^{3}\left(  \frac{7}{6}\right)  _{d/2}^{2}\left(  \frac{5}{6}\right)
_{d/2}^{2}\left(  2d\right)  !}{\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)  !\left(  3\right)
_{5d}}\sum_{i\geq0,j\geq0}^{i+j\leq d/2}\frac{\left(  -\frac{d}{2}\right)
_{i+j}\left(  \frac{d}{2}\right)  _{j}\left(  d\right)  _{j}\left(
2+3d\right)  _{i}\left(  1+d\right)  _{i}}{\left(  2+\frac{5d}{2}\right)
_{i+j}\left(  1+\frac{d}{2}\right)  _{j}i!j!\left(  -2d\right)  _{i}}.
\end{equation}

However, for dimensions $n$ or $m$ greater than 2, no analogous formulas are yet available.

Extensive numerical (quasirandom estimation) investigations

[NumericalExact](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09889)

have led to conjectures that for $n=3,m=2$ (or $n=2,m=3$) for symmetric ("rebit-retrit") density matrices the Hilbert-Schmidt probability in question is $\frac{860}{6561} =\frac{2 \cdot 5 \cdot 43}{3^8}$, and for Hermitian ("qubit-qutrit" density matrices, the corresponding probability is $\frac{27}{1000}=\frac{3^3}{2^3 \cdot 5^3}$.

However, despite these limited results pertaining to small $n,m$, Szarek, Bengtsson and Zyczkowski

[StructureBody](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/39/5/L02/meta?casa_token=y-QUxQpoM0IAAAAA:jkR3QRZj5NSWhzv2yb6Jnms7478x9tdnR95fER0Pd_hKEd0_SIX2rhwRw5uXHVvbEtc679SQOXA_OBnY9Iw) MR2200422 (2006i:81029)

were able to formally establish--specifically in the case of the Hilbert-Schmidt measure--that for all dimensions, both in the symmetric and Hermitian scenarios, the probability for the class of rank-$nm-1$ matrices is one-half that for the class of full rank ($nm$) matrices. The proof was accomplished by showing that the set of full rank ($nm$) matrices is "pyramid-decomposable", and hence is a body of constant height.

Ruskai and Werner

[RuskaiWerner](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/42/9/095303/meta?casa_token=PORWyQmIh_QAAAAA:iQtIlFa05KzzCVQUIUf7w3YkJZwXn9zecN7R8LZI31dpdX5dl-mxWvLAd6Ymmn1JJ3cre2xeqHD9zrqlwJ4) MR2525543 (2010h:81031)

have established that the probability in question is zero if the rank of the $n m \times n m$ density matrix is less than or equal to $\mbox{max}(n,m)$.

For rank-4 ($6 \times 6$) qubit-qutrit density matrices, certain numerical evidence suggests that the associated probability might be $\frac{1}{34}$ that of the rank-6 probability (conjectured, as indicated above, to be $\frac{27}{1000}$).

Additionally, other choices of measures on the density matrices have been considered (in particular, the "Bures", an example of an operator monotone measure)

```
[GeometryOfQuantumStates][4] MR3752196 (extensive review of first edition MR2230995 (2007k:81001))
```

for which a two-rebit estimate of  0.15709623 has been obtained, and a two-qubit conjecture of $\frac{25}{341} =\frac{5^2}{11 \cdot 31}$ advanced.

For asymptotic aspects of this question, see. Chap. 9 of

```
[AliceBobBanach][4]  MR3699754
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider approaching the problem from a numerical (random-matrix) viewpoint,
denoting the matrices in question by $\rho_{nm}$ and, first, considering the use of the measure generated by the Hilbert-Schmidt metric
\begin{equation}
\mbox{d} s^2_{HS}=\frac{1}{2} \mbox{Tr}[(\mbox{d} \rho_{nm})^2].
\end{equation}

Say we are interested in the proportion of $n m \times n m$ matrices of rank $k$ that remain positive-definite under the indicated operation of partial transposition, and desire to generate a matrix in that class random with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt measure.

A procedure to do so—based on the Wishart-Laguerre distribution—has been outlined (not yet published) by K. Zyczkowski and the group of A. Khevelidze, I. Rogojin and V. Abgaryan.

In the case of Hermitian matrices, one generates a $k \times k+ 2 (nm -k)$ matrix $G$, the entries of which are complex numbers, the real and imaginary parts being normal random variates. Then, $G G^\dagger$ is normalized to have trace 1. (If $k=n m$, this is the desired density matrix.
[RandomMatrix](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0405031.pdf)) If $k<nm$, the normalized matrix is diagonalized fo obtain an $k \times k$ matrix which is extended to an $nm \times nm$ matrix, the additional entries being zeros. Rotating this expanded matrix by a random unitary, the desired $nm \times nm$ matrix $\rho_{nm}$, random with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt measure on the $nm \times nm$ Hermitian, positive-definite, trace 1 matrices of rank $k$ is obtained.

In the case of symmetric matrices, one generates a $k \times k+ 2 (nm -k)+1$ matrix $G$, the entries of which are normal random variates. Then, $G G^T$ is normalized to have trace 1. (If $k=n m$, this is the desired density matrix.) If $k<nm$,  it is diagonalized fo obtain an $k \times k$ matrix which is extended to an $nm \times nm$ matrix, the additional entries being zeros. Rotating this expanded matrix by a random orthogonal  one, the desired $nm \times nm$ matrix $\rho_{nm}$, random with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt measure on the $nm \times nm$ symmetric, positive-definite, trace 1 matrices of rank $k$ is obtained.

We currently are implementing this procedure in two cases.

In one, we are analyzing $6 \times 6$ (rebit-retrit) density matrices of rank 4. Based on 675 million randomly generated (in the indicated manner) such matrices, we obtain an estimate of a probability of 0.00774073 of having a positive partial-transpose (equivalent to separability in this case).

[image: RebitRetritRank4Plot]

Relatedly, in a previous study,

[NumericalExact](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11128-019-2431-2.pdf)

we had advanced a conjecture of $\frac{860}{6561} =\frac{2 \cdot 5 \cdot 43}{3^8} \approx 0.131078$ for the $6 \times 6$ symmetric density matrices of full rank (6). (It has been formally proven that in the $4 \times 4$ counterpart, the Hilbert-Schmidt probability is $\frac{29}{64}=\frac{29}{2^6}$ [LovasAndai](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aa7176/meta) [MasterLovasAndai](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-018-1854-5https://)
.)

[image]

Now, we find it intriguing to propose a rank-4 rebit-retrit separability probability conjecture of $\frac{387}{5000} =\frac{3^2 \cdot 43}{2^3 \cdot 5^{4}} = 0.00774$. Subject to these two conjectures, the ratio of the rank-4 to rank-6 probabilities would be
$\frac{59049}{1000000}=\frac{3^{10}}{2^6 \cdot 5^6} \approx 0.059049$, with the common factor 43 cancelling.

Our second ongoing study is concerned with the rank-6 $(4 \times 2) \times (4 \times 2) $ Hermitian density matrices,  so far--based on 149 million random matrices--obtaining estimates of 0.00129085 and
0.000054624 for the full-rank and rank-6 Hilbert-Schmidt probabilities, respectively.